# Spring Security logging users activity

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, spring-security

I use Spring MVC and Spring Security to create my web application. Now I want to log all users who try to access my application. But I can't find any information about it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Define "user". What do you want to log?

Answer (score 0):

See [LoggerListener](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/LoggerListener.html):

> Outputs authentication-related application events to Commons Logging.
>
> All authentication events are logged at the warning level.